# Ant copy files from dynamic directories further down

Tags: regex, ant, copy

I am trying to copy files from some **{** dynamic **}** directories `X` into another location.

Some of the destination directories should be the **(** same and static **)** as in the source path.

The initial layout looks like this under new directory `A/D`.

```
(A)
  |_(B)
      |_(C)
          |_{X}
              |_{Y.js}
```

The final layout should look like this:

```
A
 |_D
   |_B
      |_C
         |_{X}
             |_{Y.js}
```

I tried using a regexmapper, but I am getting messages that entries are skipped because copy doesn't know how to handle it.

```
    <copy toDir="A/D/" verbose="true">           
        <fileset dir="A/" casesensitive="yes">
            <include name="B/C/**/*.js"/>
        </fileset>
        <regexpmapper from="B/C/([^/]+)/(.+\.js)" to="B/C/\1/\2"/>
    </copy>
```

Edit: I am currently trying on Windows but want this to be portable.

Comment: If I run your script without the regexpmapper tag, it seems to be working for me.   Am I missing something about what {x} represents?  As long as it stays the same under both folders, don't think you need to use the regexpmapper to change change it, right?

Comment: @mikemil, yes you're right I ended up not using the regexmapper

Comment: You might want 'answer your own question' to close this post out then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use regexmapper and here is the solution I came up with:

```
    <copy toDir="A/D" verbose="true">
        <fileset dir="A" casesensitive="no" overwrite="true">
            <include name="B/C/**/*.js"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
```